# Use Windows VPN only for certain domains/url

Tags: windows-10, vpn

I need to work at house connected on a vpn to do RDP on my work computer for reasons.

I use Checkpoint Capsule VPN on Windows 10. When i'm connected, almost all url's i type on my browser gives me a certificate error (chrome).

I want to activate the "VPN connection" only for some domains... Is that possible?